# Windows 8 on Xen Citrix Server

Tags: windows-8, xen, citrix

I want to install a windows 8 pro VM on a Xen Citrix server,

So I'm looking for an iso file with licence for 64bit Windows8 Pro, but all I can find from Microsoft's website is the upgrade from previous versions

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows/buy

There is no earlier windows machine on this server, so I need a fresh new install, but I can't find it. I was wondering if anyone else has done this before. And if so how is the procedure? and where can I buy a copy of Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

It is available from Amazon, NewEgg and many other reputable resellers in OEM and System Builder licenses.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416551 (OEM)
[http://www.amazon.com/Windows-System-Builder-DVD-64-Bit/dp/B0094NY3R0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0094NY3R0) (System Builder)

Note that the Full licnese was replaced by the system builder license / OEM license. You can browse the NewEgg options at their launching page:

http://promotions.newegg.com/microsoft/12-4171/index.html

I haven't seen it available for download from the Microsoft site (though that doesn't mean it isn't there hiding out).

Comment: Are System Builder and OEM the same? If I don't want to sell this machine which I don't, can I still use the OEM version? or does it violate Microsoft's policies?

Comment: You should use the system builder for your own systems. OEM is targeted towards resellers (though system builder allows it as well).